# python selenium getting all text in ul class

Tags: python, selenium

How can I get selenium to locate and click on each of these links in python, and copy the texts that pops up from it?

I'm looking to not do it via xpath because i'm still very new to it, but it you could give me some pointers how I can do it by the usual CSS Selectors, etc, that would be great!

```
<div class="gray-border padded">
<ul class="key-devs" data-bind="foreach: keyDevs(), visible: keyDevs().length > 0">
    <li>
        <div data-bind="text: $parent.getKeyDevLetter($index())">A</div>
        <span data-bind="text: headline, click: function(data, event) { $parent.keyDevClick($parent, data, event); }, attr: { id: $parent.getKeyDevID($index()) }" id="keyDev-A">800 Super Holdings Limited Announces Unaudited Group Earnings Results for the Third Quarter and Nine Months Ended March 31, 2016</span>
    </li>

    <li>
        <div data-bind="text: $parent.getKeyDevLetter($index())">B</div>
        <span data-bind="text: headline, click: function(data, event) { $parent.keyDevClick($parent, data, event); }, attr: { id: $parent.getKeyDevID($index()) }" id="keyDev-B">800 Super Holdings Limited Reports Unaudited Group Earnings Results for the Six Months Ended December 31, 2015; Provides Earnings Guidance for the Fiscal Year 2016</span>
    </li>

    <li>
        <div data-bind="text: $parent.getKeyDevLetter($index())">C</div>
        <span data-bind="text: headline, click: function(data, event) { $parent.keyDevClick($parent, data, event); }, attr: { id: $parent.getKeyDevID($index()) }" id="keyDev-C">800 Super Holdings Limited(Catalist:5TG) added to MSCI Acwi + Frontier Markets(acwi Fm) All Cap Index</span>
    </li>

    <li>
        <div data-bind="text: $parent.getKeyDevLetter($index())">D</div>
        <span data-bind="text: headline, click: function(data, event) { $parent.keyDevClick($parent, data, event); }, attr: { id: $parent.getKeyDevID($index()) }" id="keyDev-D">800 Super Holdings Limited Approves Tax-Exempt One-Tier Final Dividend for the Year Ended June 30, 2015, Payable on November 12, 2015</span>
    </li>

    <li>
        <div data-bind="text: $parent.getKeyDevLetter($index())">E</div>
        <span data-bind="text: headline, click: function(data, event) { $parent.keyDevClick($parent, data, event); }, attr: { id: $parent.getKeyDevID($index()) }" id="keyDev-E">800 Super Holdings Limited Proposes Final Dividend for the Year Ended June 30, 2015</span>
    </li>

    <li>
        <div data-bind="text: $parent.getKeyDevLetter($index())">F</div>
        <span data-bind="text: headline, click: function(data, event) { $parent.keyDevClick($parent, data, event); }, attr: { id: $parent.getKeyDevID($index()) }" id="keyDev-F">800 Super Holdings Limited, Annual General Meeting, Oct 23, 2015</span>
    </li>

    <li>
        <div data-bind="text: $parent.getKeyDevLetter($index())">G</div>
        <span data-bind="text: headline, click: function(data, event) { $parent.keyDevClick($parent, data, event); }, attr: { id: $parent.getKeyDevID($index()) }" id="keyDev-G">800 Super Proposes Final Dividend</span>
    </li>

    <li>
        <div data-bind="text: $parent.getKeyDevLetter($index())">H</div>
        <span data-bind="text: headline, click: function(data, event) { $parent.keyDevClick($parent, data, event); }, attr: { id: $parent.getKeyDevID($index()) }" id="keyDev-H">800 Super Holdings Limited Announces Unaudited Consolidated Earnings Results for the Year Ended June 30, 2015; Reaffirms Earnings Guidance for the Fiscal Year 2015</span>
    </li>

    <li>
        <div data-bind="text: $parent.getKeyDevLetter($index())">I</div>
        <span data-bind="text: headline, click: function(data, event) { $parent.keyDevClick($parent, data, event); }, attr: { id: $parent.getKeyDevID($index()) }" id="keyDev-I">800 Super Holdings Limited Recommends a Tax Exempt One-Tier Final Dividend in Respect of Fiscal 2015</span>
    </li>

    <li>
        <div data-bind="text: $parent.getKeyDevLetter($index())">J</div>
        <span data-bind="text: headline, click: function(data, event) { $parent.keyDevClick($parent, data, event); }, attr: { id: $parent.getKeyDevID($index()) }" id="keyDev-J">800 Super Holdings Limited Appoints Au Chee Cheong as Group Financial Controller</span>
    </li>
</ul>
<div class="no-devs" data-bind="visible: keyDevs().length == 0" style="display: none;">There is no data to show for the selected period.</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh, I solved it..

```
element = driver.find_element_by_id("keyDev-A")
element.click()
element2 = driver.find_element_by_class_name("content")
print(element2.text)
```

All I have to do now is to iterate `keyDev` from `A` to `F` :)

Comment: You should accept this as the answer so others can see that your problem was solved.